# Javascript Dates: why does my date use the wrong timezone when converting to UTC?

Tags: javascript, date

Let me start with a description of the goal. Starting with a timestamp, I need to convert a time to UTC time. Then I need to find midnight on the UTC day. Then I need to find the difference in hours between midnight and the time.

For example, I have the timestamp 1793498400153. The goal:

1. Timestamp 1793498400153 is October 31, 2026 at 22:00:00 Eastern Daylight Time (my local timezone).
2. Convert that to UTC time. It becomes November 1, 2026 at 02:00:00 GMT.
3. Find midnight. Midnight is November 1, 2026 at 00:00:00 GMT.
4. #2-#3 equals 2 hours.

My preferred technology is Javascript Date objects. Luxon is also available, but is too slow for this need.

When I use Date objects, Javascript unexpectedly jumps from daylight savings time to standard time.

For example:

1. Convert the timestamp to a Date object. Works as expected.

```
const dt1 = new Date(1793498400153)
dt1.toString()
// 'Sat Oct 31 2026 22:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
```

2. Generate a UTC time. This does not work as expected.

```
const utc = new Date(dt1.getUTCFullYear(), dt1.getUTCMonth(), dt1.getUTCDate(), dt1.getUTCHours(), dt1.getUTCMinutes(), dt1.getUTCSeconds(), dt1.getUTCMilliseconds());
utc.toString()
// 'Sun Nov 01 2026 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)'
```

That's not what I want. I would want '02:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'.

`dt1.getUTCHours()` returns `2`.

Comparing the raw timestamps, it really did move forward 5 hours, not 4:

```
(utc.getTime()-dt1.getTime())/3.6e6
// 5
```

Weirdly, if we move the timestamp back slightly before 1793498400153, the UTC time keeps the correct time zone. For example:

```
const dt2 = new Date(1793498399868.3354)
const utc3 = new Date(dt2.getUTCFullYear(), dt2.getUTCMonth(), dt2.getUTCDate(), dt2.getUTCHours(), dt2.getUTCMinutes(), dt2.getUTCSeconds(), dt2.getUTCMilliseconds());
utc3.toString()
'Sun Nov 01 2026 01:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
```

The time Nov 2, 2026 02:00:00 seems to be the magic hour at which UTC times begin to lose DST. Yet neither the United Kingdom nor the eastern US change daylight savings at that time. In any case, the core timestamp shouldn't be changed an extra hour to account for the difference.

It happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The first bit of confusion I can try to clarify is that JS Date objects don't have a concept of timezone. A JS Date object stores only a timestamp (e.g. `1793498400153`). So it doesn't make sense to "convert" this to UTC. Date.toString is just formatting this timestamp in your local timezone.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`Date.getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) function? I can't quite wrap my head around your goal but I suspect that function would make things a lot cleaner.

Comment: on all computers, smartphones, etc... the date and time elements are always in utc, and each of them knows which time zone it is on to indicate the local date and time. there is no conversion to utc to do

Comment: Another way to state the goal: I need to know the difference in time between now, at an arbitrary location, and midnight in London. To get at 'midnight in London', I'm trying to jump forward using the time zone equivalent, and then use Date.setHours to get back to midnight. In other words, if the time is 22:00 here and 02:00 in London, the goal is to be able to find that the day is 2 hours old (in London), not 22 hours old (here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to answer my own question as to why the time was doing surprising things on Nov 2, 2026 at 02:00:

The [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-local-time-zone-adjustment) calls for

> The implementation-defined abstract operation LocalTZA takes arguments t (a Number) and isUTC (a Boolean) and returns an integral Number. Its return value represents the local time zone adjustment, or offset, in milliseconds. The local political rules for standard time and daylight saving time in effect at t should be used to determine the result in the way specified in this section.

And later:

> It is recommended that implementations use the time zone information of the IANA Time Zone Database

The 'time zone database' is actually a zipped pile of files found [here](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (and make for surprisingly entertaining reading). The database says, for North America:

```
# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  -   IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
...
Rule    US  2007    max -   Nov Sun>=1  2:00    0   S
```

After the Sunday following November 1, at 02:00, switch to Standard Time. Sure enough, November 2, 2026 is a Monday, and [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States) no hard and fast rule has been set for 2026 in the United States yet, so the default is used.

That question came from a deeper misunderstanding on my part that, to calculate Date math with UTC times, zoned times needed to be converted to UTC. Javascript native Date objects measure their timestamps in UTC, so that wasn't needed. Following [ctcpip's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240469/14632909) , this code got me to my goal:

```
const dtNow = Date.now();
const dtMidnight = new Date(dtNow);
dtMidnight.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
// 1 hour is 3.6e6 ms
const hrs = (dtNow.getTime() - dtMidnight.getTime()) / 3.6e6;
```

The trick is to copy the original date, and then use `setUTCHours` to reset the hours in the context of equivalent UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

In your step 2, you are still creating a `Date` object effectively in your local timezone because the `Date` constructor interprets the arguments in reference to the system's timezone.  It doesn't matter that you're calling `getUTCFullYear()`, `dt1.getUTCMonth()`, etc. because they are just numbers you are passing to the `Date` constructor.

what you're looking for is [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```js
const dt1 = new Date(1793498400153)
dt1.toString()

// 'Sat Oct 31 2026 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'

const utc = new Date(Date.UTC(dt1.getUTCFullYear(), dt1.getUTCMonth(), dt1.getUTCDate(), dt1.getUTCHours(), dt1.getUTCMinutes(), dt1.getUTCSeconds(), dt1.getUTCMilliseconds()));
utc.toString()

// 'Sat Oct 31 2026 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'
```

Remember that Date objects just represent a moment in time; they do not actually have a timezone property.  The timezone offset and output transformation just depend on the system's locale.  You can observe this by instantiating a `Date()` object then calling `toString()` before and after changing your system's timezone.

To complete what you're trying to do:

> Starting with a timestamp, I need to convert a time to UTC time. Then I need to find midnight on the UTC day. Then I need to find the difference in hours between midnight and the time.

```js
// start with a timestamp
const dt1 = new Date(1793498400153)
dt1.toString()

// 'Sat Oct 31 2026 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'

// there is no need to "convert to UTC time".  output local time with `dt1.toString()` and output UTC time with `dt1.toUTCString()

// get UTC time
dt1.toUTCString()
// 'Sun, 01 Nov 2026 02:00:00 GMT'

// find the difference in hours between midnight and the time

// there are different ways to do this, but an easy way is to just copy the Date and set it to midnight

const dt2 = new Date(dt1);
dt2.setUTCHours(0);

dt2.toUTCString()
// 'Sun, 01 Nov 2026 00:00:00 GMT'

dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime()
// 7200000
```

Comment: Aha! That .setUTCHours was the missing piece of the puzzle. That's exactly what I need. So basically, dt1's timestamp is already in UTC (as are all Date timestamps). To find midnight on the UTC day, you have to set the Date (or a copy) to UTC midnight. The difference in hours can then be derived from some .getTime calls.

Thank you!